# Is it possible to query Azure Active Directory from an on-premises SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, openquery

I currently have an on-premises Active Directory and on-premises SQL Server. Using a linked server and OpenQuery we are able to query the AD from SQL Server.

As we are transitioning to the cloud, is it possible to do the same with an on-premises SQL Server and Azure Active Directory? If yes, any idea how?

**EDIT**:
Scenario: we have a stored procedure running every x hours that retrieves user data from the on-premises Active Directory.

Comment: Without knowing really anything about this, I can tell you this much: Azure active directory has technically nothing in common with active directory- so the answer is very probably No.

Comment: I'm *very* curious why you want to query an identity provider from a database. This sounds like the job of the application layer. And there is most likely no way since like silent said, there is almost nothing in common with AD and AAD, except the name.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks! I added some info about the scenario in the initial post, but I think you are right, it won't be feasible with AAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Graph API's to get the user info from Azure AD and dump it into any staging table.  Now you can use this staging table in your stored procedure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api

Differential Query can be used to optimize the Graph API calls.

Comment: Differential Query seems to be what we need! I was scared we would have to pull everything frequently! We'll dig into that.